# Two-sided vertical timeline

Tags: vertical, timeline

I need to make a vertical timeline about (let's say) the history of two different-but-related institutions. I was told to make it in a way that the events of one institution are placed on the left, and the events of the other institution on the right. I would like the line to be at the center of both sides, and the text on each side having the same space. I imagine something like the following image (in terms of structure):

[image]

This is what I have so fat, but the text is display differently on each side of the line: the left side is evidently for short text, such as a year. I would like to be able to write long text on both sides of the line, and the text on the left side to be right-aligned (close to the line) and the text on the right-side to be left-aligned (again, close to the line).

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\color{black}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption*{\textbf{Misiones espaciales}}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{15cm}}
\addlinespace[2ex]
   1996 & Lanzamiento del satélite SAC-B\\
   1998 & Lanzamiento del satélite SAC-A\\
   2000 & Lanzamiento del satélite SAC-C\\
   2007 & Lanzamiento del Tronador\\
   2007 & Lanzamiento del VS30\\
   2008 & Lanzamiento del Tronador IB\\
   2011 & Lanzamiento del satélite SAC-D Aquarius\\
   2014 & Lanzamiento de VEx1B\\
   2014 & Lanzamiento del satélite ARSAT-1\\
   2015 & Lanzamiento del satélite ARSAT-2\\
   2017 & Lanzamiento de VEx5A\\
   2018 & Lanzamiento del satélite SAOCOM 1A\\
   2020 & Lanzamiento del satélite SAOCOM 1B\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? for cal out nodes see `tikz` library `shapes.callouts`, page of Ti*k*Z package manual.

Comment: Thanks! I added some code and more insights of what I'm looking for. Let me know if you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.callouts}

\tikzset{spot/.style={draw, circle, fill=blue!20, outer sep=2mm},
    time/.style={inner sep=3mm, align=left},
    desc/.style={outer xsep=6mm, inner sep=2mm, below=6mm, text width=6cm, fill=blue!20, shape=rectangle callout, callout absolute pointer={(#1)}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick](0,10)
    --(0,9)node[spot](a1){}
        node[time, left]{JUN 17th\\12:00 AM}
        node[desc=a1.east, right]{1934\\ \lipsum[1][1-2]}
    --(0,6)node[spot](a2){}
        node[time, right]{JUN 29th\\11:36 AM}
        node[desc=a2.west, left]{1937\\ \lipsum[1][3-4]}
    --(0,3)node[spot](a3){}
        node[time, left]{JUL 1st\\10:30 AM}
        node[desc=a3.east, right]{1940\\ \lipsum[1][5-6]}
    --(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, thanks! it's beautiful